# JPA entity relationship between different EJB Module

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, netbeans, ejb

Currently we are developing EJB Modules for different module. It means: User, Menu etc... But is it possible JPA entities uses different EJB Module entity.

For example:

This is my Menu JPA entity in Menu EJB module.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MENU")
public class Menu implements Serializable {

    @Id    
    @Column(name = "MENU_ID", nullable = false, precision = 38, scale = 0)    
    private Long menuId;

    //getter setter
}
```

But my User JPA entity need to use Menu entity in USER EJB module.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id    
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, precision = 38, scale = 0)    
    private Long userId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "MENU_ID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Menu menuId;    

    //getter setter
}
```

When i run my unit test from User EJB Module, i get following error:

```
[class com.user.User] uses a non-entity [class com.menu.Menu] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field menuId]
```

How can i solve this? or is it possible to use?

Also what is best way to deploy these ejb module together?

Thank you,
Eba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you specify jar-file element with entity classes in persistence.xml

```
    <persistence>
        <persistence-unit name="unit_name">
        <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
        <jar-file>some_lib.jar</jar-file>
        ..................
```

Or you can directly specify entity classes:

```
<class>some.entity.ClassName</class>
```